# Issue with Web Reference after migration from BizTalk 2006 r2 to BizTalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm working on migration from BizTalk 2006 r2 to BizTalk 2010. So far upgrading solutions was successful, but when I'm trying to build project that containes Web Reference it fails with error - **Custom tool error: System.Exception: Could not generate BizTalk files. Unable to import WebService/Schema. Initialization failure. ...**

When I'm trying  to update web reference I receive message **"The custom tool ''BtsDiscoCodeGenerator failed"**.

Does anybody know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: In my experience look at the namespaces.  Usually the issues with the auto-gen tools is in reading the namespaces and unable to parse the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasons for you getting this error...

1. There may be mismatch in the namespace.
2. The WSDL for the webservice may be having more than one namespace. And biztalk do not accept a WSDL with more then one namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to rename Web Reference? Try to rename it and then update, then after, if you want, you can rename back to original name. I know its bit wired but this trick worked for me.

Comment: Renamed Web reference, but on updating I'm getting same error - "The custom tool 'BtsDiscoCodeGenerator' failed".